# Extract IP from addr using sockets

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am using python sockets to listen on a specific port and accept connections, I wish to be able to see the connection IP but there is a standard output format of the connection.

```
('127.0.0.1', 34447)
```

How do I extract just the IP from this string?

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('',23))
s.listen(10)
def tel_con():
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            printInfo(addr)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: What's the problem with indexing a tuple?

Comment: You'd use addr[0] ?

Comment: Thank you nos, you were right. Me being dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by nos the solution is addr[0]

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('',23))
s.listen(10)
def tel_con():
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            printInfo(addr[0])
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
```